# loop paddingとはなんですか

Tags: 機械学習

機械学習で動作認識を行いたいと考えています．
学習にUCF11を用いたいのですが，一部フレーム数が少ないデータが存在します．
このようなデータに対してloop paddingを用いることがあるらしいのですが，
loop paddingとはどのような手法でしょうか．

loop paddingに言及している例：
https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.02422
https://github.com/facebookresearch/video-nonlocal-net/issues/40